# delete cache by name in cache_lite

Tags: php, caching

lets assume i have these variables saved in cache_lite :

article_1_0
article_1_1
article_3_2
article_3_3
article_2_4

How can i delete all cached variables that starts with article_3_ (they can reach up to 10000) ?

or in other words , how can i list the cached variables ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save your cache_lite variables by specifying group value then try to clean it in by specifying that group value
i.e:

```
$cache->save($dataarticle_1_0,"article_1_0","article_1");
$cache->save($dataarticle_1_1,"article_1_1","article_1");
$cache->save($dataarticle_3_2,"article_3_2","article_3");
$cache->save($dataarticle_3_3,"article_3_3","article_3");
$cache->save($dataarticle_2_4,"article_2_4","article_2");
```

Then to delete all cached variables that starts with article_3_ you can do this way

```
$cache->clean("article_3");
```

Hope this is the solution